# calculate the date after 12 weeks

Tags: php

i enter the date in a variable "$date",now i want to calculate the date from $date to after 12 weeks ,how can i calculate using php.i write the following php code ,but its nt working.can anyone tell the solution

```
$month = 2;
$year = 2012;


$date = date('Y/M/d',strtotime('First Saturday '.date('F o', @mktime(0,0,0, $month, 1, $year))));
echo $date;
echo "<br/>";
$newdate = strtotime ( '+12 week' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );

echo $newdate;
```

Comment: What's the output of your script?

Comment: 2012/Feb/04
1970-03-26  but its wrong

Comment: Regarding your comment on whether to get user input and check it. What format will u use for user input??

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it helps

```
$newdate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +12 week");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$month = 2;
$year = 2012;


$date = date('Y/M/d',strtotime('First Saturday '.date('F o', @mktime(0,0,0, $month, 1, $year))));
echo $date;
echo "<br/>";
$newdate = strtotime ( strtotime ( $date ) . '+12 week' ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y/M/d' , $newdate );

echo $newdate;
```

This should be what u r looking for

Comment: How can that even work? It shows 12 weeks from now instead of 12 weeks after `$date`

Comment: i want to add some code for the above code,in that code i want to take the date from the user in a variable .how can write the code in php.can anyone help me?

Comment: @Jack, i put this code after i ran it in my local server. I take resposibility.

Comment: @Falcon The code doesn't give errors, but because `strtotime($date)` is false, it gets coerced as empty string and gives `+12 weeks`; if you feed that back into `strtotime()` you get 12 weeks from now, but that renders the value of `$date` useless. I don't blame you though, OP is pretty fuzzy about what he/she wants